# SQL Trigger Store Procedure Compile Error

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, compiler-errors

I have a question on what is giving me this error:

```
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Procedure AddIntoClass, Line 12
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_CourseEnrolled_StudentDemographic". The conflict occurred in database "PK_Final", table "dbo.StudentDemographic", column 'StudentID'.
```

This is my code so far:

```
Create Procedure AddIntoClass(@StudentID int, @CourseName nvarchar(30), 

@SectionNumber nvarchar(30), @TimeOfDay nvarchar(30), @Term int)
As 
Begin
    Insert into CourseEnrolled
    Values(@StudentID, @CourseName, @SectionNumber, @TimeOfDay, @Term)
End

EXEC AddIntoClass 2, 'Biology', '1003', '2:00pm', 2
```

Any help would be appriciated, Thanks!

Comment: Ohh and the table StudentDemographic has these columns: 
StudentID (int),  
Name(nvarchar(30)), 
Gender(nvarchar(30)), 
BirthDate(date), 
StudentStatus(nvarchar(30)), 
StudentRace(nvarchar(30)) 

and the primary key is StudentID.

Comment: Is the StudentID not in the StudentDemographic table?

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using, which is presumably SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before inserting into CourseEnrolled table, the student id value of "2", should be available in the StudentDemographic table.

You are inserting StudentId value of "2" into CourseEnrolled table, which has a foreign key reference on "StudentId" to StudentDemographic table.